# NGINX Problem with Subdir with PHP Framework

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a PHP framework that has folders like so:

```
/index.php : front controller
/controllers/* : page controllers
/models/* : models
/views/* : views
```

I set up NGINX rules such that if an explicit file or folder path is not found, it rewrites the request to index.php. I do so with this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
}

location @php {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
```

All is well and good until I want to repeat this framework into a subdirectory called "keys" for a separate web application. Now what happens is that if I call https://example.com/keys/, it calls /home/example.com/www/keys/index.php, which is correct because it's the front controller of the subdir, not the front controller of the parent folder (/home/example.com/www/index.php). But the problem is that if I call /keys/login, it's supposed to send this request to the keys/index.php front controller. Instead, it's sending the request to /index.php (root front controller). **How can I fix this so that requests for paths that include the subdir will call the proper front controller of the subdir?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another rewrite rule in your `location @php` block so that it looks like so:

```
location @php {
    rewrite ^/keys/(.*)$ /keys/index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
}
```

The `last` directive says run that rule and stop doing further rewrites in that block. So, you intercept when you detect URLs with starting folder paths of `/keys/` and send it to the proper front controller file, but otherwise send the request to the root front controller file.